# Using Bubblewrap: How to formulate get with custom headers?

Tags: ruby, http-headers, rubymotion

I have the following Curl command that works:

```
curl -H "Authorization:GoogleLogin auth=xxx" http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/user-info
```

I'm trying to do this via a `get` in BubbleWrap HTTP:

```
HTTP.get("http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/user-info",
    {
        :headers => { "Authorization:GoogleLogin auth" => "xxx"}
    }) do |response|
    puts response
    puts response.body.to_str
end
```

But I get a 401 back so maybe I didn't set the header correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header name is supposed to be `Authorization` with a value of `GoogleLogin auth=xxx`. The way you're doing it, it's a header name of `Authorization:GoogleLogin auth` with a value of `xxx`. Try this instead:

```
:headers => {"Authorization" => "GoogleLogin auth=xxx"}
```